# replace backslashes and quotation within bbcode tag php

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes, stripslashes

This string appears `as is` in my database

```
  [font=\\\"Libre Franklin\\\", sans-serif]
  This is a \\\'title 1\\\' escaped slashes \\\"content\\\" 
  [/font][/b][/font]

  [font=\\\"Libre Franklin\\\", sans-serif]
  This is a \\\'title 2\\\' escaped slashes \\\"content\\\" 
  [/font][/b][/font]

  [font=\\\"Libre Franklin\\\", sans-serif]
  This is a \\\'title 3\\\' escaped slashes \\\"content\\\" 
  [/font][/b][/font]
```

I want to remove the `\\\"` from within th `[font][/font]` bbtag, in order it stays like this

```
  [font=Libre Franklin, sans-serif]
  This is a \\\'title\\\' escaped slashes \\\"content\\\" 
  [/font][/b][/font]
```

I tried this as well...but it retrieves...and I dont know how to put them back in the string

```
 if (preg_match_all("/\[font=(.*?)\]/",$string,$matches)) 
   {
 foreach($matches[0] as $values){
          echo  $values;
   }
    }
```

It retrieves

```
 [font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif][font=Georgia][font=Georgia][font=\"Libre Franklin\", sans-serif]
```

but I dont know how sto trimm them and put them back in the string.

**what am doing wrong?**

Comment: why [font][/font][/font] seqancer

Comment: Im testing in anothert whole string where `[font][/font]` bbtag sometimes has double quotations and backslashes,....and in other cases dont.

Comment: Use the \G anchor to do these

Comment: I just want to remove those quotation marks and backslashes form the bbtags that has that characteristic, how do I put back the `$match` value to the $string? thank you.

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Use prag replece or with

`'~(?:(?!^)\G|\[font=)[^\]]*?\K\\\\\\\\\\\"~'`

with notherng

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBw4aI/1)

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. How come, preg replace, within the preg_match_all foreach?

Comment: i dont actually understand you.

Comment: have disese words not clear in hed. Somtime ok other not good